# Create an empty child record in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am trying to create a child using the Firebase data view but it seems that this is not possible as the create node directly disappears or rather doesn't show up at any time.
I tried to leave the value field empty but this doesn't work at all as well as writing null into the value field.
Am I doing it wrong?

-Fabian

Answer (score 61):

Null and empty values are the same as the record not existing. If you want it to exist, you have to set a value.

In other words, when you test for a record's existence, you aren't looking to see if the key is in the database, you are looking to see if the path (the location of that key) has any data.

Suggestion: use a falsy value like 0 or false until you have some data to throw into that location. You're not limited by data types as you would be with SQL, so you can always replace that with an object/array/et al later.

Comment: After speaking with some of the people on the Firebase Slack chat it seems that setting a value of '0' or false is unnecessary. This is because if you wanted to do checks to find out if there was some data, you can simply check if the location exists, if it doesn't it'll return null letting you know there's no data there.

Comment: I find this to be a really annoying feature of firebase. Constantly checking to see if something exists and then creating it if it doesn't is a pain, especially if your object is heavily nested as you have to check each property as you go down the chain. A database without nulls is just silly, and using something like '0' or false is a bad misrepresentation of missing data. Why not just allow nulls??!!!

Comment: Why would you have to check if it exists? What do nulls gain here? You would still look it up and get back null. There's no difference between a non-existent path and a null value. They are functionally identical.

Comment: @Kato Nulls (or any similar empty value) allow you to avoid "undefined" related bugs, thus saving you the hurdle of having to write extra code just for the sake of checking these extra edge cases.

Comment: You don't get undefined, you get null when you query the path. So that use case is handled.

Comment: On android devices with Unity, if you query a null path, you get nothing. the function just stops. The app doesn't freeze but it does stop. I used the advice above and it worked. But now I have to manage the data in a totally "clue-gee" way.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an empty directory is not Supported by Firebase.

Comment: It would be much better if you added documentation information or alternatives to the action in question.