# Firebase won't add full entirety of object when using set()

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a chrome extension and pushing data from a Google-authenticated user to Firebase.

I'm listening for a message coming from another JS file and when it comes in, I want to take the "user profile" object (request) and tack on a property to it, called "visitedLinks". visitedLinks should be set to an empty object.

I do 3 console.logs throughout the code, and in all three cases, the console.logs show "visitedLinks" set to an empty object, yet when I push to Firebase, "visitedLinks" isn't a property.

```
//Relevant 3 console statements are the following
//console.log('request.accountData = ', request.accountData)
//console.log('userObject test #1 = ', userObject)
//console.log('userObject = ', userObject)

var rootRef = new Firebase("https://search-feed-35574.firebaseio.com/");

if (localStorage.userIsAuthenticated) {
    console.log('user is authenticaled')
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        //listen for messages
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            //url is coming in from a content script, use localStorage.uid to make database call
            if (request.url) {
                console.log('message coming from content script')
                var uid = localStorage.uid;
                var url = request.url;
                var userRef = rootRef.child(uid);
                newLinkRef = userRef.push(url);
                //otherwise, we're getting a message from popup.js, meaning they clicked it again, or they've signed in for the first time
            } else {
                console.log('message coming from popup')
                //here we're passing in all the data from the person's Google user account
                var googleUID = request.accountData.uid
                    //then we make a new object with the key as their google UID and the value all the account data
                request.accountData.visitedLinks = {}
                console.log('request.accountData = ', request.accountData)
                var userObject = {};
                userObject[googleUID] = request.accountData;
                console.log('userObject test #1 = ', userObject)
                //here were checking to see if the UID is already a key in the database
                //basically, if they've ever logged in
                rootRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild(googleUID)) {
                        //user has authenticated before, they just happened to click the popup again
                        console.log('already authenticated, you just clicked the popup again')
                    } else {
                        console.log('users first DB entry');
                        //if they're not in the database yet, we need to push userObject to the DB
                        //and push their current url to the publicLinks array
                        rootRef.set(userObject, function(error) {
                            console.log('error = ', error);
                            console.log('userObject after DB insert = ', userObject)
                        });
                    }
                })
            }

            //figure out if this user has entries in the DB already
            //just push the link information onto the "links" node of the db object
            //if not, push a ref (to the right place)
            // console.log(sender)
        });
} else {
    console.log('user isnt authenticated')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that you can't insert empty objects into the database. Similar question answered here: [Create an empty child record in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911165/create-an-empty-child-record-in-firebase)